# Why my C++ object not destroyed with given value?

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++. And I got a confusing problem, hope you guys can help me. Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int t;
    A(int _t) : t(_t) {
        cout << "> created: " << t << endl;
    }
    A(const A& a) {
        cout << "> copied: " << a.t << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout << "> destroyed: " << t << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a(50);
    a = A(100);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
> created: 50
> created: 100
> destroyed: 100
> destroyed: 100
```

However, my expected output is:

```
> created: 50
> created: 100
> destroyed: 50
> destroyed: 100
```

Can you explain why is `50` not destroyed and why is `100` destroyed twice?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I add the following code:

```
A& operator=(A const& a) {                                                                                                          
    cout << "> assigned: t=" << t << " a.t=" << a.t << endl;                                                                        
    return *this;                                                                                                                   
}
```

And then output became:

```
> created: 50
> created: 100
> assigned: t=50 a.t=100
> destroyed: 100
> destroyed: 50
```

<s>It behaves normally now</s>(The first output is normal behaviour).  I might learn more about assign operator later.

Comment: @StoryTeller The actual reason for the failure is the move constructor that is used in this example... The duplicate doesn't explain this issue.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher - The move constructor is implicitly declared as deleted. It's not going to be called by anything.

Comment: @StoryTeller No, it is not. I just tried it, and if you explicitly delete it, then it doesn't compile because of the deleted move constructor.

Comment: @P.Hinker Not the reason of the failure either. The reason is the move constructor. Try it. Delete it explicitly, and then the compilation will fail.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher - If you *explicitly* delete it, it's not removed from overload resolution like an implicitly deleted move c'tor is.

Comment: foo.cpp:23:9: error: copying parameter of type 'A' invokes deleted constructor
    a = A(100);
        ^~~~~~
foo.cpp:7:5: note: 'A' has been explicitly marked deleted here
    A(A&&a) = delete;
    ^

Comment: If not for the move constructor, how do you explain this behavior?

Comment: Once again, `t` is explicitly not copied int he copy constructor, and yet `a` is modified, this has **nothing** to do with the duplicate mentioned here. It's purely the move constructor begins used.

Comment: Why are you both talking about constructors when `a = A(100)` is using the assignment operator? @MatthieuBrucher Explicitly deleting the move-constructor declares it, which implicilty deletes the assignment operator.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher - *sigh*... I match and raise your irrelevant compiler error with a [standard quote](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.funcs#8). And I explain the behavior by the absence of an initializer in the copy c'tor, and an assignment operator.

Comment: Anyway, the dupe was indeed wrong. But any answer about the irrelevant move c'tor would be wronger still.

Comment: Add this `A& operator=(A const& a) { cout << "> assigned: " << t << endl; return *this; }` and then the actual output should jibe with the expected output.

Comment: I can't understand what you're talking about. I'm new to C++ and not that smart. Can someone write a more simpler answer?

Comment: @StevenFang Ignore all comments here except for Eljay's one, and follow Eljay's advice.

Comment: Also note that while doing so will make your actual output match the output your expect, this copy assignment operator (as well as copy constructor) is broken. It doesn't copy `t` as it should.

Comment: Note carefully what HolyBlackCat said, because that's very correct.  I "broke" the assignment operator by omitting the assignment part of it (normally, that's the most important part of an assignment operator).  Fundamentally, the problem is that the original expected output is mistaken.

Comment: To trigger your copy-constructor, you need to write this: `int main()
{
    A a(50);
    // a = A(100);
    A a2(a);
    a2.t = 101;
    return 0;
}`

And that will give you desired output: `> created: 50
> copied: 50
> destroyed: 101
> destroyed: 50
`.

Welcome to StackOverflow. You now understand how things happen here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `a = A(100);` uses the [implicitly-defined copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment), which copies the value of the member `t` from the temporary to `a`.

If you want to see it in action, define it yourself like so (as per [Eljay's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140716/why-my-c-object-not-destroyed-with-given-value#comment93173491_53140716)):

```
A& operator=(A const& a) {
    cout << "> copy-assigned: " << t << endl; return *this;
}
```

Note that both this definition and your definition of the copy constructor are "broken" as they don't make any copy.

Answer (score 0):

The application output is right.
Because when you declare this object A a(50) "a" has the value 50 (a.t = 50).
Then you just change the value of "a.t = 100"
A(100) is a temporary value which is then assigned to "a.t".

So when the destructor works there is only a.t = 100.

Comment: Can I think that the `=` copy assignment operator simply copies all memory of `A(100)` to the memory of `a`, and as a result, `a.t` changes from `50` to `100`? If so, then everything is very easy to explain.

Comment: @StevenFang In this specific case - yes. In general case - no.

Comment: OK. Thank you! .

Answer (score 0):

I might have mixed C++ with Java.

In Java, `=` operator do not change left value's member. But C++ does.

So the first output is normal, and my "expected output" is wrong behaviour.

Comment: C++ supports value semantics by default.    Java supports reference semantics by default.    If you assume that C++ will do the same things as Java does, then you'll be confused in many ways when C++ does things differently.   They are different languages.